# How to configure a Linux box to forward traffic baded on mac address?

Tags: networking, iptables, network-interface, route

I configure a Linux box as a switch mode by using the below commands:

```
ip link add name switch type bridge
ifconfig switch 192.168.1.2
ip link set switch up
ip link set swp0 master switch && ip link set swp0 up
ip link set swp1 master switch && ip link set swp1 up
ip link set swp2 master switch && ip link set swp2 up
ip link set swp3 master switch && ip link set swp3 up
```

and I use `route` command to configure the routing table of this linux box, e.g.,
`route add -host 192.168.1.11 dev swp0`.
But `route` command can only L3 routing. How to configure the L2 routing? To be specific, how to configure this Linux box to forward frames by mac table which have a mac to the egress port.

Answer (score 1):

> How to configure the L2 routing?

There is no "L2 routing". Routing (finding the destination for packets not in your immediateneighbourhood) only happens on L3.

> how to configure this Linux box to forward frames by mac table which have a mac to the egress port.

If you mean "how to make sure that the bridge only sends out packets on a single port where it knows that the destination MAC address is behind that port", then this happens automatically: The bridge keeps a list of all MAC addresses it has seen together with the port, and uses only one port when it can. However, it will still send out the packet for an unknown MAC address on all ports. It also removes entries from this list when they have become too old. See e.g. `man brctl` for details.

You usually don't touch this internal list manually, because unlike routing information, it can be inferred from locally obtainable information alone.